# SVN Win Command Line Add with exclusion list

Tags: svn, controls, version

I am trying to do some automation with subversion, and have a directory where within, only certain file extensions need to be added and commited into the repository.

I wrote a vbscript that recursively searches my directory for unique file extensions, and I exclude the types of extensions in this script that I actually want to version.  I am left with a file that meets the criteria for a svn ignore list but can't figure out how to do svn add of everything in the target directory, with the exception of the file types in a list.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

- Use file as foundation of svn:ignore property and add this svn:ignore as property of FOLDER
- `svn add FOLDER` will add all content of folder (except ignored objects) into repository

**PS**: FOLDER must be a part of Working Copy